# C# Repeater.DataSource from 2 StringCollections

Tags: c#, repeater, datasource

I have 2 StringCollections:

```
StringCollection ParameterIDs
StringCollection ParameterValues
```

Is it able to map these both StringCollections as DataSource, something like:

```
repeater.DataSource = ParameterIDs (as row1) + ParameterValues (as row2);
repeater.DataBind();
```

and use them in repeater like:

```
                <asp:Repeater ID="repeatParameters" runat="server">
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        <table>
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="formLabel">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblParameterID" Text="<% #DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"ParameterIDs") %>" runat="server" MaxLength="50"></asp:Label><br />
                            </td>
                            <td class="formInputText">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblParameterValue" Text="<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"ParameterValues") %>" runat="server" MaxLength="50"></asp:Label><br />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        </table>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do exactly what you want, providing you are using .NET 3.5:

```
 StringCollection parameterIds = new StringCollection();
 StringCollection parameterValues = new StringCollection();
 parameterIds.Add("someID");
 parameterValues.Add("someValue");

 var dataSource = parameterIds.Cast<string>()
     .SelectMany(itemOne => parameterValues
     .Cast<string>(), (itemOne, item2) => new { Row1 = itemOne, Row2 = item2 });

 repeater.DataSource = dataSource;
 repeater.DataBind();
```

Like Bogdan_Ch has said, I recommend you move away from `StringCollection` to `List<string>` if you are using .NET 2.0 and above. Doing that has the added advantage that you don't need to use the `Cast` extension method.

Answer (score 5):

First thought:
Mash them up in a [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) and use that as a datasource.

Second thought:
Create a [DataSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.aspx) with the values you need.

Third thought:
Use [KeyValuePair](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.aspx).

As you see there are a lot of different ways of doing this but all of them share a common element:
Create a single object which stores and maps the corresponding values.

Answer (score 2):

No, because the DataSource requires an object with the ICollection interface.

Like the others said, you could create  a dictionary or something like:

```
List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>
```

Where the parameter id is the key, and the parameter value is the value in the KeyValuePair.

Answer (score 1):

I would populate a Dictionary with your string collections and then bind to the Dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest 2 options
1. In .NET 1.1 you don't have generic lists, so you may join collections manually in your code, and then use joined collectionas a datasource

```
        StringCollection joined = new StringCollection();

        foreach(string s in stringCollection1)
            joined.Add(s);
        foreach (string s in stringCollection2)
        {
            if (!joined.Contains(s))
                joined.Add(s);
        }
```

2. In .NET 2.0 and more I would suggest you to use List instead of StringCollection 
   With AddRange() you can add another list to an existing list.
3. In .NET 3.5 you can use Linq to intersect 2 lists

   ```
   public static IEnumerable<TSource> Intersect<TSource>(
   this IEnumerable<TSource> first,
   IEnumerable<TSource> second
   ```

   )

Comment: @Bogdan_Ch if you read the question carefully Juri doesn't want an intersection, but a projection into a new object (see my answer).